# MainActivity.java error on running the app on phone

Tags: java, android

I have made a new app on adt and now I want to run it on my phone, but It says there are two errors. Both errors are about R in `src > com.example.myfirstapp>MainActivity.java`

This is my code :

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: try cleaning your project

Answer (score 1):

I think the `resources` that you are defined is not present in your application try to correct it.

Comment: possible mistake anyone can make

Answer (score 0):

When application is building and there is some problem in code, `R.java` will not be created. But when it is created, You need to import it. If you are using eclipse, hover mouse over this error and click on Import (R. ...)